# Is it not healthy way to boil water in plastic electric kettle?

Tags: water, plastic

I am planning to buy 1L electric kettle to make green tea as I live in a hostel. 
I live in India.  Most of the products, in my budget, are made out of plastic and many comments under these product's says it's better to stay away from plastic-made products which are used for cooking/boiling.

How far these statements are correct? 
• My only need is to boil water to make green tea.  No other intentions.

Comment: Are you sure it's not lined with metal or ceramic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends, unfortunately. And it does depend a bit on budget as well.

Electric kettles used for boiling water can leach certain substances.

For plastic the main concern currently is BPA leaching.

> [What is BPA and Why Should Your Electric Kettle be Plastic Free?](https://www.bestelectrickettles.net/what-is-bpa-and-why-your-electric-kettle-should-be-plastic-free/)
>
> [Do the plastic in kettles leach the toxin BPA?](http://www.electriccordlesswaterkettle.com/do-the-plastic-in-kettles-leach-the-toxin-bpa/)
>
> [Why Electric Kettles Should Be Plastic Free](http://inthekitchen.org/electric-kettle-plastic-free/)
> Ideally, a good electrical kettle should not contain any plastic because it is loaded with BPA chemical which quickly leaks out when the temperature rises and may cause healthy concerns. BPA is found in polycarbonate, one of the raw material for manufacturing plastics. When consumed, BPA can cause some problems such as disrupting the development of the unborn child or may lead to obesity. Countries such as Japan and Canada, have banned baby bottles and sip cans which containing BPA because of the adverse effects it causes to the users.  Also, taking water or tea that tastes plastics is thought to be harmful and could cause serious health problems such as breast cancer, learning disability, and impaired learning.  BPA may also cause asthma, prostate cancer, and cardiovascular issues.

But going all metal *may* be bad as well:

> [Electric kettles may damage your health, scientists warn](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2003/feb/07/science.research)
> The government is to launch research into whether using boiled water from old-style electric kettles is worsening skin allergies through nickel leaching off exposed elements.
>
> Those who filter their water first might be exposing themselves to the greatest risk. The resulting liquid seems to be more acidic, resulting in greater concentrations of nickel dissolving into the water, although further work is being commissioned on this issue.

On the one hand you have to insist on guarantees from the manufacturer that those problematic substances are not in the product from the beginning. ("BPA-free" or something like that).
But in short: you cannot trust any industry that wants to sell something, as usual in a capitalist society. You have to find a trustworthy independent reviewer that checks for a multitude of possibly dangerous substances in those products in your market. Results can get surprising. Then choose that which best fits the paradigm of least toxic and most affordable to you.

Comment: My understanding is that when they remove BPA they replace it with BPS or other plasticizers, which are chemically similar and may have the same negative health effects. The only difference is we don't know what their effects are.

Comment: @CareyGregory Possible. From my understanding of current practise BPA and BPS seem more harmful than BPF. But that's not the point. Everything is 'toxic', we need to know the actual amounts contained/released. That's why every product needs to be tested. Not even glass, copper, cast iron, silver, ceramic as such can guarantee there are no contaminants or deliberate admixtures that might prove dangerous or at least questionable. Well, I guess, lining everything with gold might be the way to go… //  Do you mean "checks for a multitude of possibly dangerous substances" needs more emphasis or sth?

Comment: No, I think your answer is fine. My comment was merely that: a comment.